# Why does the limit of the ratio of two functions indicate a tight bound?

Tags: algorithm, function, limit, complexity-theory

My Algorithms textbook has the following excerpt:

[image]

I am struggling to understand their proof that there exists a tight bound IF the limit as n goes to infinity of the ratio of two functions is a constant.
Specifically, where do they get 0.5c and 2c from?

**My thoughts:** A tight bound means that a function T(n) is bounded above by f(n) and below by g(n). Now lets say T(n) = n^2, f(n) = an^2, and g(n) = bn^2. Then we know the tightbound of T(n) is Theta(n^2) since the ratio of f(n) and g(n) is a constant, a/b.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on other sites, possibly [math.se]

Comment: I'm happy to move it, but I am a CS student taking a CS course. Should I move this to CS stack exchange?

Comment: Yes, your thoughts (last paragraph of the question) are correct. Regarding the choice of 0.5c and 2c. That's completely arbitrary. They could just as easily have chosen 0.9c and 1.1c. Or even 0.42c and 567c

Comment: The problem with limits is that you can't say (in the general case) that the ratio is exactly some constant, only that it approaches a constant as `n` approaches infinity. In your example (in the last paragraph), you can compute the ratio of f(n)/g(n) exactly for all `n`. But given `f(n) = an^2 + n`, and `g(n) = bn^2`, you can't compute an exact (constant) ratio for all `n`. All you can say is that the ratio approaches `a/b` for large `n`.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying! If you write that as an answer, I'll give you the green checkmark.

Comment: Thanks. Given the debate as to whether this is on-topic, I think I'll pass on posting an answer. All the best to you!

Comment: btw, It wouldn't hurt to post on mathematics. It seems that the proof is implicitly using the [intermediate value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem). A good mathematician could sort that out for you.

Comment: I agree that this question belongs on the CS or mathematics SE, but in any case I think what you're looking for is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/(%CE%B5,_%CE%B4)-definition_of_limit#Precise_statement_for_limits_at_infinity.

Answer (score 0):

The formal definition of the statement "`lim w(x) = c` as `x -> infinity`" is the following:

For all `epsilon > 0`, there exists some `N` such that for all `x > N`, `|w(x) - c| < epsilon`.

Now we are given that `lim f(x) / g(x) = c` as `x -> infinity`, and that `c > 0`. Then `c / 2 > 0`.

Consider `epsilon = c / 2`. Then `epsilon > 0`, so there exists some `N` such that for all `x > N`, we have `|f(x) / g(x) - c| < epsilon = c / 2`. This is equivalent to saying `-c/2 < f(x) / g(x) - c < c / 2`, which is in turn equivalent to saying `c/2 < f(x) / g(x) < 3c / 2`.

Now since for all `x > N`, we have `c/2 < f(x) / g(x)`, then (since we always assume that `f` and `g` are positive valued) we can conclude that for all `x > N`, `f(x) > g(x) c/2`. Thus, we have shown that `f(x) = Omega(g(x))`.

And similarly, since for all `x > N`, we have `f(x) / g(x) < 3/2 c`, we see that for all `x > N`, `f(x) < g(x) (3/2 c)`. Then we have shown that `f(x) = O(g(x))`.

Thus, we see that `f(x) = Theta(g(x))`, as required.